# What conditions prevent Geralt from meditating?

Tags: the-witcher-3

First of all I would like to tell you that I know how to meditate but I tried doing that and the game prompts : "You cannot do that now." Why is it so?

Hint : I have been trying for long hours I'm not on a horse or during combat

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of How do I meditate. This is a question about the conditions for which it makes it possible to do so. Further, none of the answers on the question actually tell you the answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like the game thinks are you in combat, near an enemy, not on flat ground, jumping, on a horse, are poisoned. Or another condition of some sort.

Try using a fast travel signpost to change to a new area, and then try to meditate.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem before also. All you need to do is carry on doing main quests and it'll eventually work. I think it may be a bug when you start a certain mission. Just complete it and it'll be fine!

Comment: I couldn't meditate during "Novigrad Dreaming / Meet Corinne at the Golden Sturgeon". It was not enough to finish that quest, but after starting the next it worked again.